# place-content: center is not working as expected

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to understand why `place-content: center` is not working as expected in the given example:

```css
div {
  background-color: maroon;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  height: 2em;
  line-height: 1.3;
  width: 2em;
  place-content: center;
}

a {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="/page-2" aria-label="Page 2" aria-current="page">2</a>
</div>
```

I understand that `place-content` property is a shorthand of `align-content` and `justify-content`, so the question might be limited to why `align-content` doesn't work in the above code.

However, if I change the display property to `display: grid;`, it does work as expected:

```css
div {
  background-color: maroon;
  display: grid;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  height: 2em;
  line-height: 1.3;
  width: 2em;
  place-content: center;
}

a {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="/page-2" aria-label="Page 2" aria-current="page">2</a>
</div>
```

[The docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/place-content) state that:

> The `place-content` CSS property is a shorthand for `align-content` and `justify-content`. *It can be used in any layout method which utilizes both of these alignment values.*

Any pointers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `flex-wrap:wrap;` to be able to use `align-content` with flexbox

```css
div {
  background-color: maroon;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  height: 2em;
  line-height: 1.3;
  width: 2em;
  place-content: center;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

a {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="/page-2" aria-label="Page 2" aria-current="page">2</a>
</div>
```

> The `align-content` property aligns a flex container’s lines within the flex container when there is extra space in the cross-axis, similar to how `justify-content` aligns individual items within the main-axis. **Note, this property has no effect on a single-line flex container.**  <sup>[ref](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-flexbox-1/#align-content-property)</sup>

and

> The `flex-wrap` property controls whether the flex container is single-line or multi-line, and the direction of the cross-axis, which determines the direction new lines are stacked in.
>
> `nowrap`
>
> The flex container is single-line.
>
> `wrap`
>
> The flex container is multi-line. <sup>[ref](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-flexbox-1/#flex-wrap-property)</sup>